# Unable to redirect checkout URL to our app

Tags: shopify, checkout, shopify-app

Can we redirect the checkout URL to our sales channel app URL?.

I have created a sales channel and installed it into our storefront.

Now when customer want to checkout without login , login page is loading and after login the customer it should be redirect it to sales channel(if they come  by clicking checkout button). In page URL there is query string called checkout_url where checkout URL are given by shopify and same has been pushed into login form(HTML Hidden Field).

Now I want to replace the checkout_url(Given by shopify) with our URL(sales channel url) so that customer will redirected directly(after authenticated by shopify) to our app for checkout process.

When I am using checkout_url(given by shopify) it is redireclty to shopify checkout page. but when I am using checkout_url(my app/sales channel checkout URL ) then it is redirecting to myaccount page of shopify.

Hopefully, I explain my query.

Please help me here.